# Why does the only maximal of $k[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$ is $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, power-series, ideals

I'm trying to understand in this book why the only maximal of $k[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$ ($k$ field) is $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$:

[image]

If I prove $rad(k[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]])\subset (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, (where $rad$ is the Jacobson radical) it will imply that $k[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$  has only this maximal, so I would like to know how to prove this inclusion, it seems easy, but I couldn't see how to demonstrate this.

Thanks

Comment: Regarding your last remark: Why would the radical being inside $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ would imply that there is only one maximal ideal? In fact, the Jacobson radical of a ring is by definition inside every maximal ideal. What would indeed prove what you want, is the reverse inclusion.

Comment: @Manos I'm trying to prove this equality to prove the maximality of $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the units of $k[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$ are precisely the elements that have a non-zero constant term. I will let the proof of that to you  (hint: try to directly compute an inverse).
Hence if an element is not a unit, then it must have zero constant term. But then that means that the element must be inside the ideal $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. But that means that every other proper ideal must be inside $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and so there can only be one maximal ideal.

Comment: But the ideal $(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ are the finite sums $\sum a_iX_i$, $a_i\in k$,while a unit in $k[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$ can be an infinite sum where the constant term is not zero, as you said above. So how a unit in $k[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$ can be necessarily inside $(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$?

Comment: But i didn't say that a unit will be inside $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. On the contrary every non-unit will be inside $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and this is why $k[[X_1,\dots,X_n]]$ is local.

Comment: you said "Hence if an element is not a unit, then it must have zero constant term. But then that means that the element must be inside the ideal $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$" why the non-units is inside this ideal? just finite sums are allowed in this ideal, am I right?

Comment: Oh i see your point of confusion: not just finite sums are in $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. To see this, just apply the definition of an ideal: an element of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is of the form $X_1 f_1 + \cdots + X_n f_n$, where $f_i$ is a power series!

Comment: yes, of course, thanks!